# draw shp files or kml files on ipad?

Tags: shapefile, kml, ipad

I need to be able to draw a polygon in the field while the landowner is there to approve it.  Is there an app that is easy to use so all of the field hands can operate it? I also need to be able to export the file to be used in the equipment used to spray.

Answer (score 3):

There is an app for iOS devices that might be what you want. [My Maps Editor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-maps-editor/id389114621?mt=8) can export to KML/KMZ and works with your Google Account.

Answer (score 3):

At Cost

**GISRoam – iPad Mobile Professional GIS**

```
GISRoam WebConnect Access $9.99
GISRoam Pro $149.99
GISRoam Upgrade to Pro $129.99
```

GISRoam's App Features (requires a DataConnect activation):

• Terrain Profile display based on two points and elevation file

• Measuring now displays the elevation from the elevation file along with Lat/Long position

• User defined user forms for data collection and data display. Including pre-defined attribute table values in text/numbers/pictures/weblinks - editable while you roam.

**• Collect new shape features (Polygon, Line, Point) in new or existing Shapefile with and without the GPS**

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gisroam/id370163784?mt=8

Answer (score 3):

Another option is an online tool called [click2shp](http://click2shp.chelonialabs.com) -- it is entirely browser-based, and it allows you to draw points, lines, and polygons on top of a Google Maps basemap, and save the features as a shapefile in a single click.  It works on my iPad!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find one that I like, but 
[iCMTGIS II](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/icmtgis-ii/id516124344?mt=8) or [PrecisionEarth](http://precisionearth.com/) might provide what you're looking for at about $100 each.